# Change Unselected Tabbar item color using storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need to know how to change unselected item colour on tab bar using storyboard. I am able to change colour of selected item but the colour of unselected item is not change. So please let me know how to do this thing in objective C.

Comment: Have you try with self.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage.

Comment: add your code for selected & unselected color.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you like a newbie.
In storyboard, selected on tab bar item that can be change on the right panel, choose the color on the state which both selected and unselected.
In code, go to the definition of `UITabBarItem` , of these two methods can help you and the code below.

```
- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(nullable NSString *)title image:(nullable UIImage *)image tag:(NSInteger)tag;
- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(nullable NSString *)title image:(nullable UIImage *)image selectedImage:(nullable UIImage *)selectedImage NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is

```
[[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:index] setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```

but it would be better if you share code